# Dynamic string concatenation results in Long

Tags: jsf, xpages, el

I am currently facing a weird issue with JSF, more precisely the crippled IBM dialect called XPages.

Basically what I want is to loop over an array which is set via SSJS because EL3 isn't a thing in Xpages. So far, so bad.

I have to following source code:

```
<xp:repeat rows="3" value="#{javascript: ['1','2','3']}" var="i">
    <xp:div>
        <xp:text styleClass="columnLabel" value="Bei Zahlung innerhalb von "></xp:text>
        <xp:text value=" Tagen, "/>
        <xp:text style="font-weight: bold" value="#{crmDoc['SKONTO_PZ'+i]}"/>
        <xp:text value=" % Skonto "/>           
        <div class="cleaner4px"></div>
    </xp:div>           
</xp:repeat>
```

The type of `i` is `java.lang.String`, however, within the EL I am getting the following error (translated from German):

```
Exception while trying to convert  String "SKONTO_PZ" to type "java.lang.Long"
```

Partial stacktrace:

```
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ElException: Ausnahmefehler beim Versuch, String "SKONTO_PZ" in Typ "java.lang.Long" zu konvertieren
com.sun.faces.el.impl.Coercions.coerceToPrimitiveNumber(Coercions.java:536)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.Coercions.applyArithmeticOperator(Coercions.java:832)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArithmeticOperator.apply(ArithmeticOperator.java:101)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.BinaryOperatorExpression.evaluate(BinaryOperatorExpression.java:189)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArraySuffix.evaluateIndex(ArraySuffix.java:141)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArraySuffix.evaluate(ArraySuffix.java:170)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:163)
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:257)
com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:150)
com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:134)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:159)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1121)
```

I just don't get why on earth he's treating two strings combined with a plus as Long.

Comment: `+=` is treated as a wrong syntax. So is `.concat`. Yikes. Must be some specific XPages stuff :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments on your post are intimating, XPages EL doesn't really have proper syntax for this: `+` is addition, and then I don't think there's a string-concatenation operator. The quickest route would be to switch to SSJS for that binding.

Alternatively, if you made that `xp:div` an `xp:panel`, you could attach some `xp:dataContexts`s and do what BalusC is suggesting.

Comment: In the end, I used SSJS although I try to avoid it whenever I can. Thanks for your help!